# Only see what is inside the bounds of a container in Flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, containers

i cannot remember how i can "hide" a movieclip inside the bounds of its parent, so that i can use a scrollbar, and only see what is inside the container if i scroll down? My container is a small rectangle and contains different pictures, but we can see all the pictures even if they are outside the bounds of the parent movieclip.

Would you know how to do this? not the scroll system, just how to : only see what is inside the bounds of the container?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be masking, which can be done through the [timeline layers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WS9388626D-B940-43f3-87BB-7C3159F5EDE4.html) or [through code](http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/mask/).